# How to not match sprecific email address in regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Pythons regex to match for 2 domains and not a user starting with "bounces-.*"

Thats what i have right now:

```
^((?!bounces-)|.*)@(example\.com|example\.org)
```

This regex should match:

```
user@example.com
user@example.org
```

but not:

```
bounces-list@example.com
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
^((?!bounces-).*?)@(example\.com|example\.org)
```

You were close.The `lookahead` is working fine but your `|` operator was the culprit.Removed it.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/44#python

Comment: @Oliver - Explanation: The negative look-ahead does not "eat" any characters, so if you use `|` and  the lookahead fails (because the string starts with `'bounces-'`) the regex engine will switch to `.*` and try again from where it currently is - at the start of the string.